Proper way to open a directory?
I have a File variable pointing to folder A.
There is another folder inside - B.
What is the proper way of getting a File pointing to B?
I always used new File(folderA.getPath() + "/B") but this seems unprofessional and sometimes I need a "\".
Ideally, I'm imagining something like File folderB = folderA.enterDirectory("B"); but I couldn't find a method like this.

Path::of is your friend
